# Periodic CPU Usage Peaks in the Hostinger Hosting

Tags: database, wordpress

I see the peaks in the CPU usage in the hostinger cloud hosting. It happens without any particular pattern for around 2-3 times a day when the CPU usage peaks to more tha 50% while the normal usage is around 1-2%. The site also shows "Error in Database Connection" during this period. This period lasts for 1-2 minutes and the website becomes normal itself after that. Can you suggest me a solution for it. The hostinger staff could not solve and refered me to ask my question here at stackoverflow. Thank You.

I tried solving the problem through the Hosting Provider but they could not solve.

Comment: Getting this error in error logs

[15-Oct-2023 05:36:00 UTC] WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('rank_math_notifications', 'a:0:{}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`) made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, MyThemeShop\Notification_Center->update_storage, update_option, add_option

Comment: Use the edit link to add information to your question, please don't post it to the comments.

Comment: Is your database on `localhost` or some other machine? Do you share this virtual machine with other hostinger customers, or are you paying for a dedicated machine? Do these CPU spikes happen at the same time every day? How do you know your CPU is spiking? What monitoring tool do you use?Please [edit] your question to gve a few more troubleshooting details.